# Trying to punch a hole through a jQuery overlay, problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to do something similar to expose from jQuery toolkit.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html

Except I am trying to use an image as a background and have the overlay over it and reveal only a portion of the image as 100% visible (kind of like a reverse highlight).

My current solution is:

I make an overlay on a image background div and make the z-index of the visible section div higher than that of the overlay. But since the background of the visible section div is transparent the div just shows the overlay. The way the plugins I have seen get around this is by setting the background of the visible section div to a color allowing that whole div to set above the overlay since I am using a pretty big image, I don't have the option to use a colored background on the div. I also don't want to show a cloned copy of the original image because these background images are huge.

I couldn't find any documentation of how to do this online. I'd appreciate any feedback I could get.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've done to show? Or maybe some code?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to [absolutize](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.absolutize.js_2.txt) the element, set it to a relatively high z-index, then sit your faded layer below that, but still higher than any other content. It would give the appearance of the effect you want.